# Street view API and equirectengular projection

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-street-view

since yesterday, the Google Maps API no longer use an equirectengular projection on street view panorama. It was already happened a few month back and we have to switch to the 3.16 version of the API to make it work.

Now nothing work, all the line are distorded...

Any ideas ?

Comment: On tuesday, version 3.18 became the new standard version. 3.16 was deprecated, and you will receive version 3.17 when you request 3.16 or any prior version. Ref: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3-notify/-GqD0WKdYnM

Comment: Are you talking about the fisheye perspective of the projection?  For zoom levels <1 you still see it.  What are you doing?  Are you drawing Tron lightcycle lines, straightening the horizon, or what?  Unrelated: [what is the meaning of this](http://www.wikipeetia.org/Equirectengular_projectoin)?  lol

Comment: Thanks, this is actually the issue, with the 3.16 deprectated, there is no more distortion correction in webgl, we must use the html5 mode...